# Can't change the object attribute after changing it in the object method

Tags: python, oop, recursion

I have this little system that is supposed to solve sudoku by using the backtracking algorithm and it is in a form of a class `Sudoku_Grid_System()`. The method `solve()` is supposed to change the values from the list `sudoku_grid`. I have seen many answers to the similiar question and my code (at least to me) seems to be just correct and yet it doesn't work - after invoking the `solve()` method the `sudoku_grid` is back to its initial state. Obviously I must be missing something important.
Please, take a look at the code:

```
class Sudoku_Grid_System():

sudoku_grid = [ [5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
       [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
       [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
       [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
       [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
       [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
       [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
       [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
       [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9] ]

def __init__(self, window, grid_image, x, y):
    self.window = window
    self.grid_image = pygame.image.load(grid_image)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

......

def solve(self):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if self.sudoku_grid[i][j] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if self.is_possible(i, j, n):
                        self.sudoku_grid[i][j] = n
                        self.solve()
                        self.sudoku_grid[i][j] = 0
                return
```

When the program gets out of the loops in the `solve()` method above, the debugger tells me that the values of the `sudoku_grid` are like this:

`[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2] [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8] [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7] etc...`

But right after exiting the `solve()` method the `sudoku_grid` attribute turns back to its initial state which looks like this:

`[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0] [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0] [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0] etc...`

How to make it so that the `sudoku_grid` remains changed after all the alterations in `solve()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not supplied enough code to say definitively, but I'd say the problem is that you've no mechanism to determine if/when you've solved the square so the system backtracks all the way to the beginning.  The `solve()` method needs to return a boolean indicating if the problem has been solved and when it calls itself recursively, it needs to check that result:

```
def solve(self):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if self.sudoku_grid[i][j] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if self.is_possible(i, j, n):
                        self.sudoku_grid[i][j] = n

                        result = self.solve()

                        if result:  # solved in recursion
                            return result

                        self.sudoku_grid[i][j] = 0

                return False  # nothing worked, backtrack

    return True  # solved, no more empty squares!
```

At the top most call to `solve()`, you check it's boolean result to determine if the puzzle was solved, or if this is an unsolvable (flawed) puzzle.